# How to get a image from gallery, crop it and save it in app

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-imageview

In my project i'm using a circular image view to display a image that i get from the gallery of the phone and the image is then set to the image view up-to here everything works fine.

But the problem is when i transact from one fragment to other the image gets removed.

So i need a code snippet that helps me to pick a image from the gallery and crop it and then display the image in the image view forever.

PS: this image is also been uploaded to the Fire Base storage. so help me how can i solve this

For image extraction

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }catch (IOException e){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

for image pick

```
profileImage = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent gallery = new Intent();
                gallery.setType("image/*");
                gallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery,"Select Profile Image"), PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use this. it's image cropper
https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

for save the bitmap result to sharedPrf you should convert bitmap to base64
and for upload you should convert it to file

example for file

```
File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);
f.createNewFile();

//Convert bitmap to byte array
Bitmap bitmap = your bitmap;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

//write the bytes in file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write(bitmapdata);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

for base64:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

String base64String = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

To decode the base64 string back to bitmap image:

```
byte[] decodedByteArray = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.NO_WRAP);
Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByteArray, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Comment: Thanks and how can I save it in server or in the sharedpreferences

Comment: Thanks for the help now let me clear this. After encoding into base64 I have to pass the string to the sharedpreferences right to again use it I have to use a if statement to restore the things right.

Comment: Will you help me answering this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686659/bottom-navigation-bar-pushes-down-when-changing-between-fragments